# Can any one suggest a good networking project in python

Tags: python

I want to do a networking project using python. Can any one suggest a useful project in networking? I am aiming to complete it within next 5 months or so.

Comment: Be sure to have a look at twisted: http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/

Answer (score 6):

Without a doubt, if you want to have a good understanding with implementation, [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) is the way to go. Just by going through the documentation, you will get lots of ideas for a project.

And also, [these Twisted tutorials](http://krondo.com/?page_id=1327) (introduction) are the best (based on a question I asked earlier on SO)

Answer (score 4):

Take a simple socket or UDP based protocol and write a form of proxy using a subclass of `SimpleHTTPServer`, which manages sessions, talks to a server and allows web browsers to access the service over HTTP, thereby bringing old technologies to the world of HTML5.

I'll elaborate:

```
[Web browser with JavaScript*]
              | 
              | (talks over HTTP)
              V
[SimpleHTTPServer in Python*]
              |
              | (Has a pool of)
              |
              +--------- [TCP or UDP client 1*]
              +--------- [TCP or UDP client n*]
                                   |
                                   | (Which all talk to)
                                   V
                          [Some other servers]

* You write this part
```

The end result being that your web browser can do things that it was never supposed to do.

The simplest example could be something which manages telnet sessions, allowing a JavaScript client to play [nethack](http://nethack.alt.org/) over telnet. Other ideas along the same vein, Windows file sharing, monitoring performance counters, remote desktop / VNC and so on.

Comment: Gaz, can you please elaborate more on your first idea.

Comment: @user495600, I've drawn you a pretty ASCII picture. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks Gaz, it makes more sense now. It will help me a lot.